# error al leer una variable en PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Name

Tags: php, html, soapui

Estoy intentando leer un webservices que esta en SoapUI pero el campo que estoy intentando leer no es un nombre unico es decir que tengo varios campos con el mismo nombre esta algo a si.

```
<get1:Wallet>
           <get1:Name>PROMOTIONAL BALANCE 1</get1:Name>
           <get1:PresentValue>0</get1:PresentValue>
           <get1:AvailableValue>0</get1:AvailableValue>
           <get1:ExpirationDate>2036-12-12T00:00:00-06:00</get1:ExpirationDate>
        </get1:Wallet>
        <get1:Wallet>
           <get1:Name>WELCOMEPACK</get1:Name>
           <get1:PresentValue>0</get1:PresentValue>
           <get1:AvailableValue>0</get1:AvailableValue>
           <get1:ExpirationDate>2036-12-31T18:00:00-06:00</get1:ExpirationDate>
        </get1:Wallet>
```

yo lo que necesito es leer el campo de PresentValue, en este momento logro leer el campo si es unico y lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:
[image: Codigo HTML]

con el echo si me imprime el campo de activationDate por que es un campo unico pero no el de Name.
como podria resolver esto?

Answer (score 1):

Te muestra ese mensaje debido a que estas tratando con un objeto en este caso tu objeto contiene un array pero de tipo objeto eso cuando tu servicio te trae mas de un resultado lo que debes de hacer el recorrer tu resultado 
ejemplo:

```
foreach($array as $row)
{
  $row->nombre;
  ...
  ...
}
```

o bien convertir tu objeto a array

```
$datosArray = (array)$webService;
```

Comment: gracias, pero no estoy entendiendo como?